mysql join to record first one which is not matched before
i would like to know is it possible to join 2 tables with a condition like delist the item when it has a match for once.
Let me explain,
take a look at -- > https://dbfiddle.uk/yje6VfFz
Table name : material (which items will be produced)



refcode
bomlevel
nextbomlevel




pizza
0
0


dough
1
0


cheese
2
0


cheese
3
0


flour
4
1


water
5
1



Table name : components (which items will be used for production)



refcode
bomlevel
item




dough
0
10


cheese
0
20


cheese
0
30


flour
1
40


water
1
50


milk
2
60


milk
3
70


wheat
4
80


hidrogen
5
90


oxygen
5
100



when i run the query below
SELECT 
    c.*, m.bomlevel BomLevelOfComponent
FROM
    components c
        LEFT JOIN
    materials m ON c.bomlevel = m.nextbomlevel
        AND c.refcode = m.refcode

result table is;



refcode
bomlevel
item
BomLevelOfComponent




dough
0
10
1


cheese
0
20
3


cheese
0
20
2


cheese
0
30
3


cheese
0
30
2


flour
1
40
4


water
1
50
5


milk
2
60
null


milk
3
70
null


wheat
4
80
null


hidrogen
5
90
null


oxygen
5
100
null



now back to question...
i would like to get cheese rows on the result table 2 times as below (not 4 times).
by the way, this is not my structure, so i can not change data. i'm looking for a specified query to get the result what i need at the end.
This is my target result table



refcode
bomlevel
item
BomLevelOfComponent




dough
0
10
1


cheese
0
20
2


cheese
0
30
3


flour
1
40
4


water
1
50
5


milk
2
60
null


milk
3
70
null


wheat
4
80
null


hidrogen
5
90
null


oxygen
5
100
null



i'm trying to join 2 mysql tables but when a record match, it will be delisted not to match again.

This sounds really hard to do in SQL. Can you do it in the application language instead?

I don't understand what you are trying to do. First of all, Why don't you have unique primary keys? Why do you have duplicate reference codes? That's a really bad reference if it is not unique. Why are you not following normal relational database standards? What is a "BOM level", and why do you want that column in the result when you don't want to have "duplicate" records where that value is the only difference? It all is SO confusing. Maybe first take half an hour of learning how relational databases are supposed to work? Then repose the question so that it is clear what your actual goal is?

Hi, first of all, thank you very much for time and attention. Like i wrote before, this is not my structure. So i can not add fields as i want. But still it's not unsolvable. MS Copilot solved it. I'm gonna replay this post with the answer of Copilot.

This is MS Copilot's answer and it worked.

Copilot : Alright, so the goal is to match each component with its corresponding material, making sure no component is left out, and each
material is used only once. Here's a refined approach:

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY refcode ORDER BY bomlevel) AS rn
    FROM materials
)
SELECT 
    c.refcode,
    c.bomlevel,
    c.item,
    m.bomlevel AS BomLevelOfComponent
FROM 
    components c
LEFT JOIN CTE m 
ON c.refcode = m.refcode 
AND c.bomlevel = m.nextbomlevel 
AND m.rn = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM components sub_c 
    WHERE sub_c.refcode = c.refcode 
    AND sub_c.bomlevel = c.bomlevel 
    AND sub_c.item <= c.item
)
ORDER BY c.item;


Copilot : This ensures each cheese item gets matched uniquely with the
materials available. Both item 20 and item 30 should be included. Let
me know if this finally does the trick.
Me : yeah it works like a charm
Copilot : Awesome! Glad we finally nailed it. Persistence pays off, right? Anything else you need help with, or are we ready to call
it a win?
Me : case closed
Copilot : High five! Glad we cracked it. If any more mysteries come your way, you know where to find me. For now, take care!

